# AjaxForm upload in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, ajaxform

Im having a slight problem, if i run this code the first time, my progressbar(image) is not displayed, but if i run it the second time, without refreshing the page, then it works, i debugged this with explorer, created breakpoints where i show and hide the progressbar, the first time its not picked u, but it is the second time, anyone know why?

```
function doObjectUploadJQuery() {
var progressbar     = $('#span_upload_prog_img');
var submitbutton    = $("#upload_btn");
var myform  = $("#frm_add_attach");

$(myform).submit();
$(myform).ajaxForm({
        beforeSend: function() { //brfore sending form
                progressbar.show();
                submitbutton.attr('disabled', ''); // disable upload button
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("An error occured.");
        }, 
        complete: function(response) { // on complete
                myform.resetForm();  // reset form
                progressbar.hide();
                submitbutton.removeAttr('disabled'); //enable submit button
        }
});
```

}

Comment: You mean to say that once you submit the form again afterwards it works as intended?

Comment: Yep,as soon as the first upload is complete(and the file is uploaded), i clear the form, and do a second upload, then it works as intended

Comment: That's because you're submitting the form before you're binding the ajaxForm() plugin. If you don't have the ajaxForm bound, the submit form can't leverage it. Change the order of operations here.

Comment: that was dum of me, thanks